# Using IN-operator in query builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, query, filter

I want to filter out some bits of a layer and I want to do this in query builder in the on a text field which contains names of several countries. I cannot figure the use of `IN` as in I want to find *'India'* or *'China'* or *'Bhutan'* in field `"Territory"`. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry, _everyone_ has bad days. It doesn't make you stupid :)

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 26):

You could use something like:

```sql
"Territory" IN ('India', 'China', 'Bhutan')
```

Comment: See here about SQL `IN` operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: This question is not really about GIS stuff. It should rather be posted on other SE sites such as Stackoverflow or Database Administrators.

Comment: @wiltomap Isn't still highly relevant to GIS users?

Comment: @wiltomap that's only the case if the user is aware that QGIS query builder uses standard SQL syntax in this case

Comment: Definitely a useful answer, as not all GIS users are into the database side