# Filtering Multiple Features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, query, filter, feature-filter

**How do I select multiple features in a vector layer using the Query Builder in QGIS?**

Using U.S. Census geographic data, I'm trying to select a large number of specific block groups using the `GEOID` feature / field.

[Based on an answer found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211642/using-in-in-query-builder-in-qgis?rq=1) and using the `LIKE` operator, I've used the following query in the Query Builder:

```
"GEOID" ILIKE ('34013000100%', '34013000200%')
```

This results in error:

`OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected ','.`

I've also tried using the `LIKE` and `IN` operators; changing the wildcard from `%` to `_` (a single underscore); and other separators replacing the comma, all with error results.

I note that filtering for a single value (such as `"GEOID" ILIKE ('34013000100%')` works fine.

A sample data file is found [here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2016/shp/cb_2016_34_bg_500k.zip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing a multiple LIKE statement with the values you're trying in an IN statement.

In the image below, there are 2 sets of selected features for each LIKE statement (highlighted in pink):

```
"GEOID" like ('34013000100%')  
or  
"GEOID" like ('34013000200%')
```

[image]